# java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on developing mule connector in Java which call a rest endpoint and for this we are using httpclient v4.5.13 with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager but intermittently getting connection timed out (read failed).

According to logs we have noticed SocketException - timed out occurs after about 17 minutes. For httpclient the default socket timeout is 60 seconds so not sure why it takes 17 mins to throw this exception.

Error logs

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:962)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
```

Here is the snippet of code to build httpclient.

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
pool.setValidateAfterInactivity(5000);
this.setProtocol(protocol);
this.setHost(host);

this.httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(pool).build();

// 5. Execute the POST request
CloseableHttpResponse httpresponse = this.httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Any help will be appreciated ?